# PANDAS : How to filter a dataframe based on index (mixed type) )

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter my dataframe based to the type of my index.
My index has string, NaT or date.
**I only want to keep the rows with date in the index.**

I tried the below but it doesn't work. I get

> keyError: False

```
df = df[isinstance(df.index, datetime)==True]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to parse the index to datetime index, then use `notna` to check for the rows which have valid datetime values

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').notna()]
```